# I need help writing a complex SQL statement

Tags: sql, nested, max

```
**PLEDGE TABLE**
PledgeID  PledgeAmount  PledgeDate   DonorID   
---------|-------------|------------|---------
1        | 100         | 04/03/2014 | 1
2        | 200         | 04/03/2013 | 1
3        | 100         | 04/03/2009 | 2
4        | 2,000       | 01/01/2012 | 3
5        | 1,000       | 01/01/2012 | 4
6        | 500         | 01/01/2009 | 4

**DONOR TABLE**
DonorID   Name           SpouseID    
---------|-------------|-------------
1        | John Smith  | 3
2        | Jack Johnson| NULL
3        | Jane Smith  | 1
4        | John Adams  | NULL
```

I have 2 tables: a Donor table and a Pledge table. I want to run a query that returns only one record per couple (specifically the max or most recent pledge date) who have given in previous years but not this year. This is very important for our non-profit since the best people to solicit donations to are past donors. However, in our database sometimes the wife gives and the next year the husband gives so it is under both. Some are not married.

So in the above table, only John Adam's pledge in 2012 and Jack Johnson's pledge in 2009 should be returned. Jane Smith should not be returned even though she has not given since 2012 because her husband gave this year.

Comment: It would help a lot if you told us which database this is for.  Not all implementations of SQL are the same so "sql" by itself does not tell us enough about which style of SQL to offer as a solution. Is you database MS SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL? Postgres?etc.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but something like the following should work:

```
(select dt.donor_id, null spouse_id, max(pledge_date) maxDate
from donor_table dt inner join pledge_table pt on (pt.donor_id = dt.donor_id)
where dt.spouse_id is null group by dt.donor_id
having max(pledge_date) is not null and max(pledge_date) < '2014-01-01'
union distinct
(select dt.donor_id, dt.spouse_id
      ,case when max(pt1.pledge_date) is null then max(pt2.pledge_date) else when   
       max(pt2.pledge_date is null then max(pt1.pledge_date) else   
       greatest(max(pt1.pledge_date), max(pt2.pledge_date)) end maxDate
 from donor_table dt left outer join pledge_table pt1 on (pt1.donor_id = dt.donor_id)
 left outer join pledge_table pt2 on (pt2.donor_id = dt.spouse_id)
 where dt.donor_id < dt.spouse_id
 group by dt.donor_id, dt.spouse_id
 having case when max(pt1.pledge_date) is null then max(pt2.pledge_date) else when   
       max(pt2.pledge_date is null then max(pt1.pledge_date) else   
       greatest(max(pt1.pledge_date), max(pt2.pledge_date)) end is not null 
 and case when max(pt1.pledge_date) is null then max(pt2.pledge_date) else when   
       max(pt2.pledge_date is null then max(pt1.pledge_date) else   
       greatest(max(pt1.pledge_date), max(pt2.pledge_date)) end < '2014-01-01'
 )
```

The first query return values for donors who have no spouses.  The second returns pairs for couples  where I use dt.donor_id < dt.spouse_id to avoid duplicates.  Also in that query I do a left outer join in both cases otherwise you might miss results. There may be minor syntax errors but something like that should work.  I also put the date '2014-01-01' so that it returns donors you gave in 2013 or before but not in 2014

And I am using the greatest function from mysql.

It looks  complicated because I am repeating

```
 case when max(pt1.pledge_date) is null then max(pt2.pledge_date) else when   
       max(pt2.pledge_date is null then pt1.pledge_date else   
       greatest(max(pt1.pledge_date), max(pt2.pledge_date)) end
```

To simplify you could define a function for that. It's basically computing the greatest value of the spouse and donor where one  or more values is null

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly which database you are using make proposing a solution much harder. I assume your database supports common table expressions and the `concat()` and `year()` functions. If this isn't true there are simple alternatives.

This is the suggested solution:

```
with couples as (
    select 
           case when d.SpouseID IS NULL then concat('',(d.DonorID * -1))
               when d.SpouseID < d.DonorID then concat(d.SpouseID,d.DonorID)
               else concat(d.DonorID,d.SpouseID)
           end as combinedid
         , case when d.SpouseID IS NULL then d.name
                when d.SpouseID < d.DonorID then concat(s.name,d.name)
                else concat(d.name, s.name)
           end as names
    from Donors d
    left join Donors s on d.spouseid = s.donorid
    )
select distinct
     couples.names, p.MaxPledgeYear
from couples
left join (
    select
          case when d.SpouseID IS NULL then concat('',(d.DonorID * -1))
               when d.SpouseID < d.DonorID then concat(d.SpouseID,d.DonorID)
               else concat(d.DonorID,d.SpouseID)
          end as combinedid
        , max(year(PledgeDate)) MaxPledgeYear
    from pledges p
    left join donors d on p.donorid = d.donorid
    group by
          case when d.SpouseID IS NULL then concat('',(d.DonorID * -1))
               when d.SpouseID < d.DonorID then concat(d.SpouseID,d.DonorID)
               else concat(d.DonorID,d.SpouseID)
          end
    ) p on couples.combinedid = p.combinedid
where p.MaxPledgeYear < 2019
```

It produced the following result:

```
+----------------------+---------------+
|        names         | MaxPledgeYear |
+----------------------+---------------+
| Jack Johnson         |          2009 |
| John Adams           |          2012 |
| John SmithJane Smith |          2014 |
+----------------------+---------------+
```

From this result you can exclude any rows that have "donated in this year" using a where clause. As "this year" is already well past 2014, nobody in that list has pledged for "this year" yet.

More detail:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Pledges(
>    PledgeID     INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
>   ,PledgeAmount VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL
>   ,PledgeDate   DATE  NOT NULL
>   ,DonorID      INTEGER  NOT NULL
> );
> INSERT INTO Pledges(PledgeID,PledgeAmount,PledgeDate,DonorID) VALUES (1,'100','04/03/2014',1);
> INSERT INTO Pledges(PledgeID,PledgeAmount,PledgeDate,DonorID) VALUES (2,'200','04/03/2013',1);
> INSERT INTO Pledges(PledgeID,PledgeAmount,PledgeDate,DonorID) VALUES (3,'100','04/03/2009',2);
> INSERT INTO Pledges(PledgeID,PledgeAmount,PledgeDate,DonorID) VALUES (4,'2,000','01/01/2012',3);
> INSERT INTO Pledges(PledgeID,PledgeAmount,PledgeDate,DonorID) VALUES (5,'1,000','01/01/2012',4);
> INSERT INTO Pledges(PledgeID,PledgeAmount,PledgeDate,DonorID) VALUES (6,'500','01/01/2009',4);
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Donors(
>    DonorID  INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
>   ,Name     VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL
>   ,SpouseID INTEGER 
> );
> INSERT INTO Donors(DonorID,Name,SpouseID) VALUES (1,'John Smith',3);
> INSERT INTO Donors(DonorID,Name,SpouseID) VALUES (2,'Jack Johnson',NULL);
> INSERT INTO Donors(DonorID,Name,SpouseID) VALUES (3,'Jane Smith',1);
> INSERT INTO Donors(DonorID,Name,SpouseID) VALUES (4,'John Adams',NULL);
> ```

> ```
> with couples as (
>     select 
>            case when d.SpouseID IS NULL then concat('',(d.DonorID * -1))
>                when d.SpouseID < d.DonorID then concat(d.SpouseID,d.DonorID)
>                else concat(d.DonorID,d.SpouseID)
>            end as combinedid
>          , case when d.SpouseID IS NULL then d.name
>                 when d.SpouseID < d.DonorID then concat(s.name,d.name)
>                 else concat(d.name, s.name)
>            end as names
>     from Donors d
>     left join Donors s on d.spouseid = s.donorid
>     )
> select
>      *
> from couples
> ```
>
> ```
> combinedid | names               
> :--------- | :-------------------
> 13         | John SmithJane Smith
> -2         | Jack Johnson        
> 13         | John SmithJane Smith
> -4         | John Adams
> ```

> ```
> select
>       case when d.SpouseID IS NULL then concat('',(d.DonorID * -1))
>            when d.SpouseID < d.DonorID then concat(d.SpouseID,d.DonorID)
>            else concat(d.DonorID,d.SpouseID)
>       end as combinedid
>     , max(year(PledgeDate)) MaxPledgeYear
> from pledges p
> left join donors d on p.donorid = d.donorid
> group by
>       case when d.SpouseID IS NULL then concat('',(d.DonorID * -1))
>            when d.SpouseID < d.DonorID then concat(d.SpouseID,d.DonorID)
>            else concat(d.DonorID,d.SpouseID)
>       end
> ```
>
> ```
> combinedid | MaxPledgeYear
> :--------- | ------------:
> 13         |          2014
> -2         |          2009
> -4         |          2012
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5c1faa1f10035c16b9f534253cb09608)*